# EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length accepts bad sizes for blowfish

Tags: c, openssl

When I try to set the key length of an `EVP_aes_128_cbc` envelope to 58, via  `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length`, I get the following error:

```
3073369856:error:0607A082:digital envelope routines:EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length:invalid key length:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:557:
```

That makes sense because EVP_aes_128_cbc only supports key sizes of 128 bits or 16 bytes.

What doesn't make sense to me is when I do the same thing for `EVP_bf_cbc` I don't get any errors at all.

According to [wikipedia's entry on Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)) the maximum bitsize is 448 bits or 56 bytes, which is less than 58. Further, quoting http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+5.+Symmetric+Encryption/5.18+Using+Variable+Key-Length+Ciphers+in+OpenSSL/, "*OpenSSL puts a hard limit of 256 bits on key sizes*".

My code:

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <string.h>
void handleErrors(void);
int main (void)
{
  unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567";
  unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"01234567";
  unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *)"xxxxxxxx";
  unsigned char ciphertext[128];
  int plaintext_len = strlen((char *)plaintext);
  int len;
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
  ERR_load_crypto_strings();
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
  OPENSSL_config(NULL);
  if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();
  if (!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL)) handleErrors();
  if (!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(ctx, 58)) handleErrors();
  if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv)) handleErrors();
  if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len)) handleErrors();
  if (1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
}
void handleErrors(void)
{
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  abort();
}
```

Replace `EVP_bf_cbc` with `EVP_aes_128_cbc` to reproduce the error. I wouldn't be surprised if I got an error in `EVP_EncryptInit_ex` (with `EVP_aes_128_cbc`) since the iv isn't equal to the block size but the code is aborting before that point, anyway, so it's somewhat moot it seems to me.

Comment: It may be a validation issue in OpenSSL. I'm guessing the library sets the key to 56-bytes internally. Maybe you should bring it up on one of the OpenSSL mailing lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length()` is only helpful where a cipher has a variable key length (which is the case for Blowfish). The function does some limited validation on the supplied key length. If the cipher has a fixed length key, then it will check that the supplied key length is the same as the fixed length. Otherwise it will return with an error.

If using a cipher with a variable length key then it just checks that the key length is positive. Otherwise you can set any value that you like. It doesn't really make a difference because when Blowfish comes to use it, it checks that the key length is sane, and uses a reduced length if it is too long:

```
static int bf_init_key(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const unsigned char *key,
                       const unsigned char *iv, int enc)
{
    BF_set_key(&data(ctx)->ks, EVP_CIPHER_CTX_key_length(ctx), key);
    return 1;
}
...
void BF_set_key(BF_KEY *key, int len, const unsigned char *data)
#ifdef OPENSSL_FIPS
{
    fips_cipher_abort(BLOWFISH);
    private_BF_set_key(key, len, data);
}

void private_BF_set_key(BF_KEY *key, int len, const unsigned char *data)
#endif
{
    int i;
    BF_LONG *p, ri, in[2];
    const unsigned char *d, *end;

    memcpy(key, &bf_init, sizeof(BF_KEY));
    p = key->P;

    if (len > ((BF_ROUNDS + 2) * 4))
        len = (BF_ROUNDS + 2) * 4;
```

Here BF_ROUNDS == 16, so the maximum key length is 72 bytes (576 bits). I'm not particularly familiar with Blowfish, so I don't know why the discrepancy between this and the 448 bits you mention above.

Edit:
Ah, the discrepancy is probably due to this (from wikipedia):
"Because the P-array is 576 bits long, and the key bytes are XORed through all these 576 bits during the initialization, many implementations support key sizes up to 576 bits."

Comment: *"Here BF_ROUNDS == 16, so the maximum key length is 72 bytes (576 bits). I'm not particularly familiar with Blowfish, so I don't know why the discrepancy between this and the 448 bits you mention above"* - Schneier says its 448-bits; see [The Blowfish Encryption Algorithm](https://www.schneier.com/academic/blowfish/). Maybe there's been an update to the algorithm.

Comment: I just tried passing 100 to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length()` with `EVP_bf_cbc`. Didn't get any errors. Looking at the code snippet you posted that's no surprise - looks like it just silently resizes it if the size is too big and it's a varialbe length cipher. Seems like it *ought* to give an error instead. Oh well..