# Verify "PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC" is generating required byte of key

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I am not getting a correct length of key generated by "PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC" oppenssl api.

I am expecting a length of key will be 32 (ie 32*8 = 256 bits).

Am i doing something wrong or missing something here?

```
        unsigned char key[32];
        bzero(key,sizeof(key));

        const char * password1 = "locpasswordkey";
        size_t plen = strlen(password1);
        const char * salt = "fixedsaltlengthsforenc";
        size_t slen = strlen(salt);
        if(PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(password1, (int)plen, (const unsigned char *)salt, (int)slen,65536, EVP_sha256(), (int)sizeof(key), key) == 0)
        {
                cout << "PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_KEY() failed" << endl;
        }
        cout << "KeyLen: " << strlen(key) << endl
```

How we can be sure that "PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC" is generating required bits key.

Using this key i am performing decryption, but "EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length" function reporting below error

error:0607A082:digital envelope routines:EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length:invalid key length:evp_enc.c:651:

Below is my decryption function.

```
std::string decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv ) {

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;
    unsigned char* plaintext = new unsigned char[ciphertext_len];
    bzero(plaintext,ciphertext_len);

    
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleOpenSSLErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleOpenSSLErrors();

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(ctx, EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH);

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleOpenSSLErrors();

    plaintext_len = len;

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleOpenSSLErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;

    plaintext[plaintext_len] = 0;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    std::string ret = (char*)plaintext;
    delete [] plaintext;
    return ret;
}
```

Any thoughts will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your use of `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC` is correct, and does not contribute at all to your error.

First of all, to use `_set_key_length` you need to split your Init so you can set the algorithm, then the key length, THEN the key. See e.g. [EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length accepts bad sizes for blowfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867197/evp-cipher-ctx-set-key-length-accepts-bad-sizes-for-blowfish) and [OPENSSL Blowfish CBC encryption differs from PHP to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210723/openssl-blowfish-cbc-encryption-differs-from-php-to-c) (which, note, are for Blowfish, which is variable-key; AES in OpenSSL EVP is not).

But if you are using OpenSSL 1.0.1 or higher, which you probably are, `EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH` is 64, and 64 bytes is NOT a valid key size for AES ever much less for `EVP_aes_256_cbc` as you have here which is a fixed-size instantiation, and moreover 64 also is NOT the size of your actual key, so even if it did somehow accept your call it would use garbage data for the key and produce totally wrong and useless results.

Don't do that.